# How to use a custom org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter with RabbitListener annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm using Spring 4.2 and spring-amqp 1.5.5 and I've implemented my own `org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter`. This message converter is supposed to map between a `org.springframework.amqp.core.Message` and a Java object by looking at a property contained in the message body. But I cannot find a way to apply this message converter to be used in combination with the `@RabbitListener` annotation. What I want to do is something like this:

```
@RabbitListener
public void process(MyEvent myEvent) {
..
}
```

But Spring seems to be using a `DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory` to which you can only assign instances of  `org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter` which is not the same type of MessageConverter that I'm using.

The reason for implementing my own `org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter` is because we generate messages from non Java applications which doesn't add the magic `__TypeId__` header used by Spring to determine the class to deserialize the body into.

I have tried to define a `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory`:

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
    factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
    return factory; 
}
```

but it doesn't seem to be used (or at least it doesn't make any difference).

So my question is, how do I apply my `org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it the correct way, so something else must be happening, perhaps the bean is being overridden by another definition? You could try giving the bean a different name and explicitly reference it in the `@RabbitListener`.

We have lots of test cases that test this feature [this one for example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/annotation/EnableRabbitIntegrationTests.java#L851) and its [use here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/annotation/EnableRabbitIntegrationTests.java#L1028).

By the way, in the upcoming 1.6 release [the type from the listener method is provided to the converter](https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/25/spring-amqp-1-6-0-milestone-2-and-1-5-5-available) which helps with missing `__TypeId__` headers.

Comment: You're right, there was another bean definition overridding it (that had the same name). As a side note I wonder why I spring didn't complain about duplicated bean definitions in my case. Thanks a lot for the hint!

Comment: That is normal Spring Framework behavior - it's intended to work that way to allow, say, an application to override a bean definition that's in a jar.